# Is it normal to get ETA: 6:43:26 hours to complete the first epoch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data, vgg-net, model-fitting

I have crated the below vgg16 based CNN and I want to train it for 50 epochs. but it shows nearly 7 hours (ETA: 6:43:26) to complete the first epoch. could anyone please tell me is this normal with 209222 training images and 40000 validation images(DeepFashion dataset) ? or is this any issue with my steps_per_epoch? I use a HPC with 16 workers to train this model.

```
  train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

  val_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

  train_batches = train_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
          target_size=(img_r, img_c),
          batch_size=batch_size,
          class_mode='categorical',
          shuffle=True)
          
  val_batches = val_gen.flow_from_directory(validation_path,
          target_size=(img_r, img_c),
          batch_size=batch_size_val,
          class_mode='categorical',
          shuffle=False)
  
  return train_batches, val_batches



def fit_model(model, batches, val_batches):

    print("started model training")
    history = model.fit(train_batches,
                                  steps_per_epoch = 209222/32,
                                  epochs = 50,
                                  validation_data= val_batches,
                                  validation_steps=40000/32,
                                  verbose=1,
                                  use_multiprocessing=True,
                                  workers=16
                                  )
```

this is the model part

```
def create_model(input_shape, output_classes):
    logging.debug('input_shape {}'.format(input_shape))
    logging.debug('input_shape {}'.format(type(input_shape)))
    
    #optimizer_mod = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=momentum, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
    
    vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
  
    for layer in vgg16.layers[:15]:
        layer.trainable = False
    
    x= vgg16.get_layer('block4_conv3').input
    x = vgg16.get_layer('block4_conv3')(x)
  
    if True:
        x = Reshape([28*28,512])(x)
        att = MultiHeadsAttModel(l=28*28, d=512 , dv=64, dout=512, nv = 8 )
        x = att([x,x,x])
        x = Reshape([28,28,512])(x)   
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        
    #x = vgg16.get_layer('block5_conv1')(x)
    #x = vgg16.get_layer('block5_conv2')(x)
    #x = vgg16.get_layer('block5_conv3')(x)
    #x = vgg16.get_layer('block5_pool')(x)
    
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = Dense(output_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    
    
    model =tf.keras.Model(inputs=vgg16.input, outputs=outputs)
    
    top3_acc = functools.partial(keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy, k=3)
    top3_acc.__name__ = 'top3_acc' 
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    
    model.compile(
                  optimizer=opt,
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy',top3_acc]) 

    return model
```

Comment: I am making a guess here. But is your gpu active? You can test like this  ```tf.test.is_gpu_available() ```

Comment: Thankyou so much for you answer, I have tested the GPU , its not in active state, and also seems like it gets nearly 7 hours to run every epoch :( , what could be the reason for this, I have also added my model code , is this because the way I have packed the model ?

Comment: @EdwinCheong and also i have another question, How can I enable the GPU ? I haven't a gpu on my lap. I am using the university HPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using VGG then you should rescale the values between -1 and +1 as

that is how it was trained so use

````
rescale=1/127.5=1
```
That will not solve your long epoch 1 problem however. 
For steps_per_epoch and validation steps use
````

steps_per_epoch= 209222//32+1
validation_steps= 40000//32 +1

```
That will also not solve the problem I suspect. 
Each training epoch will require 6539 steps and each validation 
will require 1251 steps. This is really rather large.
Now the processing time will be greatly dependent on the image size. 
What values did you use?
Also the VGG model has on the order of 40 million trainable parameters 
so it is computationally intensive to begin with. I would recommend 
using the Mobilenet model which has on the order of 4 million parameters
and is about as accurate. As noted by Edwin Cheong above  you need to
check if your GPU is being used. I suspect it is not.
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer. The Image size I have used is 224*224. the training process is still running, and seems like it gets nearly 7 hours to run each and every epoch :( . I have changed the steps_per_epoch and validation_steps, but still it is same as before. What could be the reason for this? As am a newer for this field, am little afraid whether this happens because of the way i have packed the layers :( ?could this be the reason? I have also added my model part, or anyway is it better to change the model as you have mentioned above ?

Comment: ,I am using the university HPC, I have no GPU in my lap

Comment: without a gpu times will be very long. If you us 128X 128 images it will take about 1/4 as long. If I were use I would use Mobilenet aswell

Comment: Thank you so much @Gerry P . I created the Mobilenet model and start the training again. now it shows nearly an hour time per epoch. Is this normal? .and Can we use this Mobilenet model to train any large no of Images which is larger than 2GB image datasets ?

Comment: yes I have used it on very large data sets. You also might speed up processing by using a larger batch size.

Comment: got it :)  .Thank you very much @Gerry P. This means a lot to me.

Comment: if satisfied please mark answer as accepted